# Template variable for email in Django allauth socialaccount signup

Tags: django, django-allauth

What template variable does the email field in the form in socialaccount /signup.html in Django allauth use?

In the `allauth/templates/socialaccount/signup.html` there is this form:

```
<form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'socialaccount_signup' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}
  <button type="submit">{% trans "Sign Up" %} &raquo;</button>
</form>
```

To style the fields and delete labels I want to drop the form and use my own input fields. I can extract the tags inspecting the from in the browser but the `value=` from the email input field is already populated with my email address and I can't see the variable it uses.

Can you help me with it?

I tried to find it in the source code but i can't understand it. It seems that it renders the SocialAccount model in the form. I have tried from `value="{{ email }}"` to `value="{{ socialaccount.get_social_account().user.get_email() }}"` everything.

Comment: Probably form has it in initial_data try looking in views or forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'socialaccount_signup' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="email" name="email" id="id_email" value="{{ form.email.value }}" placeholder="Your Email Address" required>
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}
  <button type="submit">{% trans "Sign Up" %} &raquo;</button>
</form>
```

I've replaced the `{{ form.as_p }}`. To populate the email file use the value attribute with `{{ form.email.value }}`. I hope this is helpful.